# Convert mass text to utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8

I am receiving an xml feed of product information. The information is in English, but it is not encoded in `utf-8` (smart quotes, copyright symbols, etc.). To process the information, I need to convert it into `utf-8`.

I have tried doing variations of:

```
u'%s' % data
codecs.open(..., 'utf-8')
unicode(data)
```

But for every one I've tried I get a `UnicodeDecodeError` (of various sorts).

How would I convert all this text into `utf-8` ?

**Update**

Thanks for the help, here is what ended up working:

```
encoded_data = data.decode('ISO 8859-1').encode('utf-8').replace('Â','')
```

I'm not sure where the `Â` came from, but I saw those next to some copyright symbols.

Comment: Do you know what charset it's currently in?

Comment: @Ignacio - if I had to guess I would say `ISO-8859-1`, but I'm not certain. How would I find this out?

Comment: How are you receiving the feed?

Comment: Then you need to ask whoever provided the file.

Comment: Not quite sure what you want here...
Write a python program to do it? Can't help you.
Just trying to convert it? This might help. <http://macchiato.com/unicode/convert.html>

Comment: Why use a web page when `iconv` exists?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to convert it to UTF-8, you need to know what encoding it's in.  Based on your description, I'm guessing that it's in one of the Latin-1 variants, ISO 8859-1 or Windows-1252.  If that's the case, then you could convert it to UTF-8 like so:

```
data = 'Copyright \xA9 2012'  # \xA9 is the copyright symbol in Windows-1252

# Convert from Windows-1252 to UTF-8
encoded = data.decode('Windows-1252').encode('utf-8')

# Prints "Copyright © 2012"
print encoded
```

Comment: More likely Windows-1252 since he said the text has smart quotes

Comment: If there are unmapped symbols in the lower 0x80 region (0x80 ... oxa0, don't remember exactly) there is an older dos/windows code page below 1000, 85x or so, which for the rest is very similar to cp1252.

Comment: @wildplasser: Are you thinking of [CP 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)?  That's commonly used in DOS/DOS-like environments and is the default hardware code page of most Windows PC sold in the US and Western Europe.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than guessing the encoding, you could let [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) guess on your behalf:

```
import chardet

def read(filename, encoding=None, min_confidence=0.5):
    """Return the contents of 'filename' as unicode, or some encoding."""
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        text = f.read()
    guess = chardet.detect(text)
    if guess["confidence"] < min_confidence:
        raise UnicodeDecodeError
    text = unicode(text, guess["encoding"])
    if encoding is not None:
        text = text.encode(encoding)
    return text
```

Comment: I like this idea, but using it on the files I have raises the same `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: Have you tried calling `chardet.detect()` manually on the content of the file? This function is set up to raise `UnicodeDecodeError` when chardet isn't confident in its guess ...

Comment: Worked for me on OCR'd texts that ended up in 4 different charsets. Brilliant, thanks.